# Path cannot be found in django

Tags: python, django

I am working on a django project. The project includes 2 apps namely jobs and blog. The url.py of the main project file is:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
import jobs.views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', jobs.views.home, name= 'home'),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

You can understand that I am calling the output of the jobs in the home. The url.py of the blog is:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.allblogs, name= 'allblogs'),
]
```

and the views.py of the blog is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def allblogs(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/allblogs.html')
```

This gives an error that the blog/ can not be found. I must mention I make a allblogs.html in the address project/blog/templates/blog The webpage shows that it tries to find the page in this ditrectory: ...project\jobs\templates\blog\allblogs.html

The error message is:
TemplateDoesNotExist at /blog/
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/blog/
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist

I dont know why it is trying to find it in jobs where it should search for it in blogs folder.
Can someone help? May be I have done something silly..

Comment: Please show the full error message.

Comment: You say that "blogs/ can not be found", but your URL is `blog/`, without the "s".

Comment: sorry, it should be blog/ cannot be found. sorry for the typo. So, blog/ is still not found

Comment: In the TEMPLATE section of your settings.py file you can define where django looks for your templates. Is there a reason why you do not want to put the template into the jobs/templates folder and reference to it with just "allblogs.html"

Comment: upload your settings.py file

Comment: please show your configuration of the templates ( `TEMPLATES` )  and also the folder/file structure

Comment: Also please provide the path where you saved your template, maybe the directories are just incorrect.

Comment: in your settings.py in `TEMPLATES` >check if your dirs is empty like this: `'DIRS': []` if so add the following code: `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],` and remove the `return render(request, 'blog/allblogs.html')`to `return render(request, 'allblogs.html')`.